# Laravel's whereHas not filtering fetched results for a relationship (one-to-many)

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have been trying to filter **students** belonging to a **sub-class** based on a filter criteria (say the last name of the student). 
In my *Laravel 5.0* app, I have models `Subclass` and `Student` where their relationship and class definition are as follows:

*Relationship*:

`Subclass` ***HasMany*** `Student`(s)

*Model definitions:*

```
class Subclass extends Eloquent {

   .
   .
   .

    public function students() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Student');
    }
}
```

---

```
class Student extends Eloquent {

   .
   .
   .

    public function subclass() {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Subclass');
    }

    public function scopeFilterStudents($query, $filter){
       return $query->where('last_name', 'like', '%'. $filter .'%');
    }
}
```

***The Issue***:
The problem arises when I try to filter the **students** in a particular **subclass** using `whereHas` as such:

```
$students = Subclass::whereId(1)->whereHas('students', function($query){
      return $query->filterStudents(Input::get('filter'));
  })->get();
```

I've followed the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#querying-relations) on filtering queried models and technically, it should be working, but it isn't filtering as expected (*in fact, it isnt filtering at all and I don't get a `students` key if I cast the result into an array*).

***Workaround:***
On the other hand, if I eager load (*below*) the fetched models (i.e. with `with` method), the models are filtered with the same filter criteria (*AND, I do get a `students` key if the returned collection is cast into an array*).

```
  $students = Subclass::whereId(1)->with(['students' => function($query){
      return $query->filterStudents(Input::get('filter'));
  }])->get();
```

- ***Note:*** The `id` specified here using `whereId` is optional, as omitting it would take all sub-classes into account.

***So, is there any problem with my implementation of the `whereHas` method, or else, does the `whereHas` itself have any issue(s) filtering models.***

Any help in this regards would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're fetching objects of the wrong model. What you're doing in your first approach is fetching all `SubClasses` that have an ID of 1 and at least one `Student` record to which the given filter applies. So if you want to get `Students` of this `SubClass`, you can simply invert the query:

```
$students = Student::whereHas('subClass', function($q) use ($subClassId) {
    return $q->whereId($subClassId);
})->filterStudents(Input::get('filter'))->get();
```

Your second approach is valid as well, but you're fetching a `SubClass` with its `Students`, so if I got your explanation right, you get more than you actually want or need.

---

It is also possible that I missunderstood your question and you're trying to get all `Students` that have at least one relation to a `SubClass`. If so, you can use this query:

```
$students = Student::has('subClass')->get();
```